# How can static files in your Apache server DocumentRoot be served even when the server isn't running?

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, server

I'm new to Apache server and noticed that when I go to `localhost:80` that it will open up the default resource (`index.html`) in my `/var/www/my_domain` directory, as defined by my `my_domain.conf` file when the server has been stopped.

It makes sense that a static resource would be able to open since my browser is just rendering the contents but I don't understand how my browser would know which directory to look in when the apache server isn't running.

Comment: You have a http server running and looking in that directory for files.

Comment: Port 80 is therefore open.  So some software is listening on port 80 to produce that result.  Check your system, something else than the Apache you are expecting is running.